# CakePhp load model in other model and modify its data

Tags: cakephp

I have Comment model and Video model connected with belongsTo and hasMany relation. I need in controller of Comment (in one action) load connected video, change its one attribute and then save comment and video. I know how to change comment model but I can't change Video model in any way.

This is my function:

```
    $this->Comment->id = $id;
    if($this->Comment->exists()){
        $this->loadModel('Comment');
        $this->Comment->set('accepted', 1);
        if($this->Comment->save()){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Comment accepted');
            //HOW TO CHANGE ATTR OF VIDEO
            //in $this->Comment->video_id there is NULL
        }
        else
            $this->Session->setFlash('Can't accept comment');

        $this->redirect($this->request->referer());
    }
    else{
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid comment'));
    }
```

Can you help me guys?

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

First, you don't need to call this at all:

```
$this->loadModel('Comment');
```

Just above the line where you call `$this->loadModel('Comment');`, you've got a line saying `$this->Comment->id`. `$this->Comment` is an instance of your comments model. In Cake, each controller has an instance of it's corresponding model, accessible by `$this->ModelName`.

Second, your comments model will in turn have an instance of your video model. So, your Video model will already be accessible via your comments controller, at `$this->Comment->Video`

So, to modify the video model, you'd fist have to get the Comment's video_id, and then do this:

```
$this->Comment->Video->id = $videoId;
$this->Comment->Video->set('accepted', 1);
$this->Comment->Video->save()
```

Comment: But how can I get data from Video. I need to get present value, modyfi it and save it. Also when I do: $this->Comment->Video->id = $videoId; and the Video not exists it is created in DB (all attrs empty)

Comment: You're already getting a present value, modifying it, and saving it for Comments - so you just use the exact same logic for Video, only you access it via $this->Comment->Video, rather than $this->Comment

Comment: $this->Comment->video_id is null. $this->Comment->Video->rate is null. I found solution to read comment as array, get video_id, read video, read value and modify it

Comment: You would expect that $this->Comment->video_id should be null - it's not a valid way to get that property. You should read the full doco at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html and http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html, it'll give you a good picture of how everything fits together.

Comment: You dont need to get the value of the record to modify it. just follow  ing @joshua.paling you will get the record with the $videoId use ->set('field', 'value) to modify and then ->save() to save the changes.